# How To Detect If User Has iOS App Installed In Browser - Like Example Site In Post

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am wondering how this site detected that I have their iOS app installed when I visited their web site on my phone.

http://drafthouse.com/austin

[image]

Comment: Great example, BTW... I love (and miss) the Alamo Drafthouse :)

Comment: any idea how to detect if the app is installed from another button? meaning, the user clicks on a button, if the app is installed she goes to the app otherwise to the app store? no smart banners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sites can implement Safari Smart App Banners. See Apple's documentation for details:

> [Promoting Apps with Smart App Banners](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

It is done via something like this:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

Answer (score 1):

These are called [Smart App Bannners](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) and are a feature of MobileSafari on iOS 6. You can add these using literally one line of HTML code (a `<meta>` tag, see the linked docs).